# .htaccess rewriterule to remove locale in symfony2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I need to remove locale from url in htaccess symfony2
for example:

site.de/de/....

to

site.de/....

symfony default htaccess looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

how can i remove locale in a safe way without breaking any routing.

Comment: remove it from your url-mapping e.g "routing.yml" instead of using .htaccess

Comment: @johnSmith i have multy domain system. and i need to cut locale just on some hosts

Comment: did you know you can have host specific routing.yml ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

Comment: @johnSmith yes i know. but im using kunstmaan bundles framework and i dont want to touch their  routes.